# Value of un-initialized enum in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, enums

If i have a class that contains an `enum` member and that member is not initialized with any data.

I want to check if some value has been placed (sort of validation mechanism I am making for the class to validate all members has been initialized), what can I compare the `enum` member to? `NULL`? Or it receives 0 (0 is like the first field so that would not be good for anyone..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare an un-initialized variable with anything, because it's undefined behavior to read it.

So your safest bet is to keep an `UNSET` state as part of the `enum`, initialize it to this state, and compare it with that.

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior?  I thought it was "unspecified value".

Comment: Nope, UB. You have to initialize it yourself if you want some kind of uninitialized value.

Comment: Interesting... so it's different from C.

Comment: No, it's UB in C too- at least prior to C11.

Comment: Nope.  Both automatic variables and `malloc()` results are "indeterminate values", defined as "either an unspecified value or a trap representation" -- see C99 3.17.2 (definition of "indeterminate"), 6.2.4 (for local variables), 7.20.3.3 (for `malloc()`).  If you know your platform does not have trap representations, then it is safe to access such values.

Comment: @DietrichEpp the two aren't exclusive. The value can be indeterminate **and** result in UB if you attempt to read from it.

Comment: Yes, quite right.  But in C99 `printf("%d\n", *(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)));` does not invoke UB unless your integers have trap representations, which is extremely rare.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Why didn't you write directly `int x; printf("%d", x);`?

Comment: Same reason I didn't write "very" when I wrote "extremely" -- the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: @DietrichEpp well, are they any different?

Comment: According to the C99 standard, if your platform has no trap integers, both will print out unspecified values -- that is, any value whatsoever, but not UB.  The `malloc()` version also leaks memory.

Comment: @DietrichEpp C99 is pointless here. I agree in C it might be ok, and I'm not sure about C++ (I was before you questioned it). I remember seeing this some time ago, but can't dig up the quote now. It might be something with l/r-value conversion.

Comment: I just brought it up to catalog the differences between C and C++.